# Perl's Net::(SSH vs SSH2 vs OpenSSH) -- how should I compare them?

Tags: perl, ssh, perl-module

Looking to execute a perl script on a remote machine via a Perl script. Appears one option is to use [system()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function and create an ssh key so the password is not required. Which leads me to the focus of this question, the other option appears to be to install and run one of these perl modules:

- [Net::SSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net%3a%3aSSH)
- [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net%3a%3aSSH2)
- [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH)

Besides the protocol used, what else should I be comparing with these Perl modules?

Comment: Did you see that the Net::OpenSSH documentation page that you linked to has an entire section devoted to this topic titled "Net::OpenSSH Vs Net::SSH::.* modules"?

Comment: @indiv: +1 Brad Gilbert linked to those pages via an edit to my question, and I'll take a look at it -- thanks!!

Comment: @indiv: Please post your comment as an answer, and I'll except it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::OpenSSH) documentation has a [section](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-OpenSSH/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm#Net::OpenSSH_Vs_Net::SSH::.%2A_modules) describing the pros and cons of each.  Here are some excerpts related to the ones you are asking about, but the documentation lists more:

> **[Net::SSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::SSH)** is just a wrapper around any
>   SSH binary commands available on the
>   machine. It can be very slow as they
>   establish a new SSH connection for
>   every operation performed.
>
> **[Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::SSH2)** is much better than
>   [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::SSH::Perl), but not completely
>   stable yet. It can be very difficult
>   to install on some specific operative
>   systems and its API is also limited,
>   in the same way as [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::SSH::Perl).
>
> **[Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::OpenSSH)** has a very perlish
>   interface. Most operations are
>   performed in a fashion very similar to
>   that of the Perl builtins and common
>   modules (i.e. [IPC::Open2](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html)).

However, choice of platform may limit your options.

> On the other hand, [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::OpenSSH) does
>   not work on Windows, not even under
>   Cygwin.

Granted, the list is biased towards [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::OpenSSH), but it gives you an idea of the major differences between the modules.